# How i can select multiple arry in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

Hi guys i need to select the name and event and the email and search in them not just one of them as you can see when i put getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; i have the search in name and when i put getElementsByTagName("td")[2]; i can search in event but i need to search in all 3 of them just 3 not all of them 
Thanks for your help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-inverse tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header">
        <th> 
            <input type="checkbox" value="All" id="selectIDs" />
            </label>
        </th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Event</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Iban</th>
          <th>UID</th>
          <th>Date</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
             <% uids.forEach(function(uid){ %>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="productIds" value="<%=uid._id%>"></td>     
              <td ><%= uid.name %></td>
              <td ><%= uid.event %></td>
              <td ><%= uid.email %></td>
              <td><%= uid.iban %></td>
              <td><%= uid.uid %></td>
              <td><%= uid.readableDate %></td>

            </tr>
          <% }) %>

          </tbody>

    </table>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use an array with the 3 elements by row you need, as

```
let newArray = new Array();
if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
```

And then do you search in this array :

```
if (newArray.filter((e,i) => e.indexOf(filter) > -1).length > 0) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
     tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Or

```
if (newArray.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
     tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

If you want to check each letter or the full word.

Is this better ?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     let newArray = new Array();
  if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]);
  if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]);
  if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]);
      if (newArray.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}    like this ? not working

Comment: no :/ its not working you can see here you can put the code and test it  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbytagname_all   i can run it  here

Comment: ok I update my answer (hope you use jQuery, otherwise tell me)

Comment: its work some how but its show all 3 when i press any letter,,
  let newArray = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
 if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
 if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]) newArray.push(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML.toUpperCase());
    if (newArray) {
      if (newArray.filter((e,i) => e.indexOf(filter) > -1).length > 0) {

Comment: it displays the line as soon as there is one letter in common

Comment: yes, like this  anas holi Email but its so much better becouse when i press a or h or e the line sill the same, but another letter the line diessper

Comment: Thanks for your help i will look to it monday it's friday night it's time to party :)